How to convert 2 TS Tuples, names and types, to {[names]: [types]}
I have two TS tuples (and let's throw in a helper that I can get):
type names = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
type types = [number, string, number];
type indicies = [0, 1, 2];

And I want:
type returnType = {a: number, b: string, c: number}

I can't figure out how to actually create this.  Anything like [K in ...] necessarily uses K as the key.  So I can get {0: number, 1: string, 2: number}, but can't figure out how to make the names to the keys.
I feel like I'm probably ignorant about some feature in TS.

The feature you're missing is key remapping in mapped types. See the linked q/a above for more information.

You can iterate index of the first tuple and get keys and values from the corresponding tuples:
Playground
type names = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
type types = [number, string, number];


type Obj = {[K in keyof names as K extends `${number}` ? names[K] : never]: types[K]};
/*
type Obj = {
    a: number;
    b: string;
    c: number;
}
*/

